# Is it possible to add a dashboard to a experience site using metadata that works for different environments?

Tags: metadata, dashboard, experience-cloud

I'm using the ExperienceBundle Metadata API and I have an experience site. There are a couple of dashboards that are part of a managed packaged that I want to include in my experience site. I added them manually to my site and retrieved the metadata into my project in visual studio code. I see that the metadata includes the Ids (in the property dashboardId) of the dashboard and these Ids will be different in other environments. Is there a way to include them using another reference?
[image: Metadata of one dashboard]

Comment: From my experience, no we can't unfortunately. Although the component will be added the link to the dashboard breaks in the deployment and it's often a post deployment step to correct this.